# Accessing only the second object in a directive and making a template

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to understand how directives work in AngularJs, this is the object I'm working with but its much more complex than the regular exercises with much more easy objects to manage.

```
angular.module('AngularJsExercise.controllers', []).
        controller('angularJsExerciseController', function($scope, angularJsServices) {
            $scope.advisor = {
                        name : "TheTitle",
                        pages: [
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                pageNum: 0,
                                pageText: "First Page",
                                questions: [
                                    {
                                        id: 11,
                                        questionText: "I am looking for a new printer for...",
                                        questionType: "RADIO_BUTTONS",
                                        mandatory: true
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                id: 2,
                                pageNum: 1,
                                pageText: "Second Page",
                                questions: [
                                    {
                                        id: 22,
                                        questionText: "Printer should have..",
                                        questionType: "CHECKBOX",
                                        mandatory: false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        id: 22,
                                        questionText: "What color ?",
                                        questionType: "CHECKBOX",
                                        mandatory: false
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                id: 3,
                                pageNum: 2,
                                pageText: "Third Page",
                                questions: [
                                    {
                                        id: 33,
                                        questionText: "I am looking for a new printer for...",
                                        questionType: "RADIO_BUTTONS",
                                        mandatory: true
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                id: 4,
                                pageNum: 3,
                                pageText: "Fourth Page",
                                questions: [
                                    {
                                        id: 44,
                                        questionText: "Price range",
                                        questionType: "SINGLE_SLIDER",
                                        mandatory: false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        id: 444,
                                        questionText: "Printer size",
                                        questionType: "DOUBLE_SLIDER",
                                        mandatory: false
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    };
```

I want to make a template only with the second part of the object, the"pages", but it also brings me the first part which is the title, how can I display/represent a single page element with all of its atributtes in this type of complicated object? Here is my directive:

```
angular.module('AngularJsExercise.controllers')
            .directive('advisorPage', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope:{
                        data: '='
                    },
                    // template: "<h1>{{advisor.name}}</h1>", <-- I want this part to have all of the attributes of the second object to display.
                    controller: function($scope){
                        console.log($scope.data);
                    },
                    templateUrl: 'advisorPage.template'
                };
            });
```

And Here's the last part

```
    angular.module('AngularJsExercise', [
        'AngularJsExercise.services',
        'AngularJsExercise.controllers',
        'AngularJsExercise.filters'
    ]);


<div ng-app="AngularJsExercise" ng-controller="angularJsExerciseController">
        <!-- display pages with questions -->
        <div ng-repeat="adv in advisor"> 
            <advisor-page data='adv'> </advisor-page> 
        </div>

        <!-- advisorPage directive template -->
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="advisorPage.template">

        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: What if you rearrange the contents of $scope.advisor in another way, maybe to be directly an array? This way the ng-repeat will iterate over the elements of that array. Another option will be to iterate on advisor.pages instead of advisor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you correct you need to create a directive that would represent one page and use it in the loop.

```
<advisor-page page="page" ng-repeat="page in advisor.pages">
  <page-question question="question" ng-repeat="question in page.questions"></questions> 
</advisor-page>
```

You can then use [ng-transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) to nest directives inside each other for each entity you want to represent. You directive would look like

```
angular.module('AngularJsExercise.controllers')
.directive('advisorPage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      page: '='
    },
    template: '<div class="page-wrapper">' +
              '<p>{{page.pageText}}</p>' 
              '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' + 
              '</div>'
  };
});
```

So you can wrap one directive in to another and display any information you want.

Comment: it works but i get this error 
Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/ngTransclude/orphan?p0=%3Cng-transclude%3E
    at Error (native)

Comment: Hey!, could you help me a bit more?I just wanna know how to add the questions in each page too to the template thanks!